# combo box does not work properly

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, listeners

I have here a simple ordering system which requires the user to input cashier name, customer name and password. After the user completes that process it will then show a combo box that contains different meals.

What I want to happen is that once I clicked a meal, it should display the name of the meal I selected and should perform the action I declared in the actionlistener.

The program compiles fine but the logic I want to happen isn't working, I'm trying my best to fix this but I think I can't do this on my own please help me thanks!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;


public class SubokUlit {
    private JComboBox combo;
    private String a  = "";
    private static int answer;
    private static int total = 0;
    private static int total1 = 0;
    private static int wew = 0;
    private static String order1 = "";
    private static String order2 = "";
    private static Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);


 public SubokUlit(){
    String mgaPagkainTo[] = {"PM1 (Paa/ Spicy Paa with Thigh part)","PM2 (Pecho)"};    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mang Inasal Ordering System");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    combo = new JComboBox(mgaPagkainTo);
    combo.setBackground(Color.gray);
    combo.setForeground(Color.red);
    panel.add(combo);
    frame.add(panel);
        combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ // The logic in here does not work
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String str = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
        a = str;
        if(a.equals("PM1 (Paa/ Spicy Paa with Thigh part)")){ // If I select PM1 in the combo box it should do the following. But it doesn't work
                 System.out.print ("\n\n\n\t\tYou have chosen Paborito Meal 1.\n");
                    System.out.print ("\t\t\tPlease enter the quantity: ");
                    int quantity1 = inp.nextInt();
                    total = quantity1 * 99;
                    order1 = quantity1 +  " " + "PM1 " + "                                   " + total +"\n";
        }
        else if(a.equals("PM2 (Pecho)")){ // The same thing should alaso happen here in PM2
            System.out.print ("\n\n\n\t\tYou have chosen Paborito Meal 2.\n");
                System.out.print ("\t\t\tPlease enter the quantity: ");
                int quantity2 = inp.nextInt();
                total1 = quantity2 * 99;
                order2 = quantity2 +  " " + "PM2 " + "                                   " + total1 +"\n"; 
        }
    } 
    });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
}


public static void main(String[]args) {
      Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in); 
      String userNamePoe  = "";
      String customerNamePoe  = "";
      String sanKaKain  = "";
      boolean ulitinMoPows = true;
      boolean tryAgain = true;

        System.out.print("\nInput Customer Name: ");
        String customerName = inp.nextLine();
        customerNamePoe = customerName;
        System.out.print("\nInput Cashier Name: ");
        String user = inp.nextLine();
        userNamePoe = user;
     do{
        System.out.print("\nInput either Dine In or Take Out: ");
        String dInDOut = inp.nextLine();
        sanKaKain = dInDOut;
            if (sanKaKain.equals("Dine In") || sanKaKain.equals("Take Out")){
             System.out.print("");
             ulitinMoPows = false;
             }
            else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try again! Please input Dine In or Take Out only!","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 ulitinMoPows = true;
                 System.out.print ("\f");
                }
     }while(ulitinMoPows);
     do{
        System.out.print("\nInput password: ");
        String pass = inp.nextLine();
        if(pass.equals("admin")){
            System.out.print("");
            tryAgain = false;
        }
        if(!pass.equals("admin")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try again! Invalid password!","Error Logging-In", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        tryAgain = true;
         System.out.print ("\f");
        }
}while(tryAgain);

        System.out.print("\n\n\t\tCashier: " +userNamePoe);
        System.out.print("                          "+sanKaKain);
        System.out.print("\n\t\tCustomer Name: " +customerNamePoe);

        SubokUlit j = new SubokUlit(); //Supposedly, once the selecting of meal is done, it should now go to the next part wherein the total bill will display and asks the user how much is his cash.


    int lahatNgOrderMo = total + total1; 
    double multiplierVat = 0.12;
    double vatCollected = lahatNgOrderMo * multiplierVat;
        System.out.print("\n\n\tYour total bill is: "+lahatNgOrderMo); // Displays the bill
        System.out.print("\n\tCash Tendered: "); // Asks the user how much is his cash
    double cashTendered = inp.nextInt();
    double sukliMo = cashTendered - lahatNgOrderMo;


        System.out.print("\n\n\t\t                         MANG INASAL");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t                     BLUMENTRITT BRANCH");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t         #1631-1633 BLUMENTRITT ST.,");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t            STA CRUZ. MANILA 0000");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t               (932) 885-5844\n");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t            Operated by: R L YU");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t            TIN 202-161-017-000 VAT");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t        ACC. NO.: 050-204079836-000019");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t             Tel. #: (02)493-6801");
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\tCashier: " +userNamePoe);
        System.out.print("\t\t   STATION: 2");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tO.R #: 84486");
        System.out.print("                          "+sanKaKain);
        System.out.print("\t\t\n                Customer Name: " +customerNamePoe);
        System.out.print("                        24");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t                 >>SETTLED<<\n\n");
        System.out.print(""+order1);
        System.out.print(""+order2);
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\tSUB TOTAL:                              "+lahatNgOrderMo);
        System.out.print("\n\t\tDELIVERY VAT:                            0.00");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t                                       ======");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tAMOUNT DUE:                              "+lahatNgOrderMo);
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\tVAT 12% COLLECTED                    "+vatCollected);
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\tCASH Tendered:                         "+cashTendered);
        System.out.print("\n\t\t                                       ======");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tCHANGE:                                 "+sukliMo);
        System.out.print("\n\t\t              >>Ticket #: 62<<");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t      Created: ");
        System.out.print("\n\t\t      SETTLED: ");
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\t*********************************************");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tTHIS SERVES AS AN OFFICIAL RECEIPT.");
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\tFor Feedback: TEXT MIO467(Comments/ Suggest");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tions)  and  SEND  to  0917-5941111 or CALL US");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tat 0917-5596258");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tEmail: feedback@manginasal.com");
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\t     THANK YOU FOR DINING WITH US!");
        System.out.print("\n\n\t\t*********************************************");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tS/N: 120416ASL03/1105-6105-9230");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tDT S/N: 41-L6971 (P0S1)");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tPERMIT NO: 0412-031-125295-000");
        System.out.print("\n\t\tMIN: 120276752");


} 
}
```

Comment: where is the problem ? What is it exactly ? What have you tried ? where are you stucked ?  Any of these questions answered could help us.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk the logic in the actionListener doesn't work. Everytime I click a meal in the combo box it doesn't perform the actions I declared

Comment: @Angel Casi Montoya I've edited my answer. Can you try the code entered there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure an eventlistener is attached to your JComboBox, so the application knows what to do when something happens.

In this case, you want to attach an [`ItemListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html).

You can use something like this:

```
combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Meal chosen: " + combo.getSelectedItem().toString());
        String optionalParameter = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        DoMethodWhatYouNeedToDoWhenYouSelectedSomething(optionalParameter);
    }
});
```

EDIT: Your code should be like this:

```
combo.addActionListener(new ItemListener(){ 

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
        String str = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
        a = str;
        if(a.equals("PM1 (Paa/ Spicy Paa with Thigh part)")){ 
             System.out.print ("\n\n\n\t\tYou have chosen Paborito Meal 1.\n");
             System.out.print ("\t\t\tPlease enter the quantity: ");
             int quantity1 = inp.nextInt();
             total = quantity1 * 99;
             order1 = quantity1 +  " " + "PM1 " + "                                   " + total +"\n";
        }
        else if(a.equals("PM2 (Pecho)")){ 
            System.out.print ("\n\n\n\t\tYou have chosen Paborito Meal 2.\n");
            System.out.print ("\t\t\tPlease enter the quantity: ");
            int quantity2 = inp.nextInt();
            total1 = quantity2 * 99;
            order2 = quantity2 +  " " + "PM2 " + "                                   " + total1 +"\n"; 
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: You mean to say I have to switch to ItemListener instead of actionListener? Please check out my code above

Comment: Yes, and rename the `actionPerformed` to `itemStateChanged`. Check my edit :)

Comment: Sir it says <anonymous SubokUlit$1> is not abstract and does not override abstarct method. What should I do?

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: On the line combo.addActionListener(new ItemListener(){

Comment: Is that the complete error message?

Comment: Oh wait! `itemStateChanged(ActionEvent e)` should be `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)`. Let me update my answer.

Comment: No. This is the full error meassage: <anonymous SubokUlit$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent) in java.awt.event.ItemListener

Comment: Have you tried to change ActionEvent into ItemEvent?

Comment: Yes, it still gave me an error, I tried to change ActionListener to ItemListener and it compiled. I tried to run the program but it still doesn't work properly